# Подсвечивание элемента управления

Tags: c#, winforms

Кто-нибудь знает, как сделать подсвечивание контролла как в майкрософтском paint'е?
[image: Подсветка]

Т.е. изначально, как я понимаю, у инструмента задан фоновый цвет. А когда на него наводишь мышкой, фон немного светлеет. Причем снизу яркость увеличивается больше, чем сверху

Comment: насколько я понимаю, это не подсвечивание фона а замена. Т.е. у вас должно быть 3 фона: пассивный элемент, активный элемент, элемент под курсором. Ну и переключаете их соответствующим образом

Comment: @rdorn, ну да, понятно, что замена. Просто снизу фон ярче оказывается, чем сверху, вне зависимости от положения курсора на этом контролле

Comment: это называется градиентная заливка. В WinForms ее руками надо делать либо брать готовую текстуру и подставлять. Но это однозначно делается текстурным фоном а не цветом.

Comment: @rdorn, окей, спасибо

Comment: Тогда оформляю в виде ответа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эффект о котором вы спрашиваете называется градиент - плавный переход от одного цвета к другому. Простым изменением цвета фона такого эффекта добиться нельзя.

В WinForms нет готовых средств для получения градиента, но можно вместо этого подставить подходящую текстуру в качестве фонового изображения.

Таким образом задача сводится к получению нужной текстуры, а для этого можно либо в ручную раскрасить `Bitmap` так как вам нравится, либо заранее подготовить текстуру в удобном графическом редакторе.

Если требуется строго вертикальный или строго горизонтальный градиент, то размер текстуры может быть `1 * n` или `n * 1` пикселей соответственно. `n` подбирается для получения нужной плавности градиента.

Для получения эффекта нужно установить необходимую текстуру в свойство `Control.BackgroundImage` и выставить нужное значение для масштабирования фона в свойстве `Control.BackgroundImageLayout`, например `Stretch` для текстур размера `1 * n` или `n * 1`.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ